# stop service not working on logout click in android

Tags: android, web-services, service, android-service

i have service class , inside that class for every 15 minutes i am calling the webservice, if i logout the application the service should stop and webservice shoud not call , i tryed to use stopService but its not working please help me to do this

SERVICE CLASS:

```
`class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{} public Location getLocation()//using this i am getting the location
```

I Have used the timer to send the webservice

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MultipartEntity params = new MultipartEntity();
            try {
                params.addPart("value", new StringBody("live_feed"));
                params.addPart("latitide", new StringBody(String.valueOf(latitude)));
                params.addPart("longitude", new StringBody(String.valueOf(longitude)));
                params.addPart("security_id", new StringBody(Helper.loadSavedPreferences(mContext,"security_id")));
                Log.d("Security ID", Helper.loadSavedPreferences(mContext,"security_id"));
                new JSONParser(mContext, new GpsListener()).execute(params);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

In another Helper class i am just stoping the service but its not working

`activity.stopService(new Intent(activity,GPSTracker.class));`

Answer (score 2):

You should bind your services `onResume`, and unbind them `onPause`. This should keep the service from working if you aren't in the application.

You could also call `timer.cancel()`, so long as you've stored a reference to the timer. Just be warned that you need to create a new timer to use it again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the base context to stop when you click the logout button.

```
 stopService(new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), GPSTracker.class));
```

bind and unbind service are to create a service connection between the service and activity, so that the activity can access the service though the service instance.